# padding in percent to div that have no parent height

Tags: html, css

For example i have only one div in body

```
    .sample {
        padding-top: 20%;
    }
```

We don't have any parent with height. From what we calculate this percent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The padding top is calculated :

```
padding-top = 20% of parent width;
```

For class `sample`, the parent is body. So the parent width is width of body which is browser width.

Comment: Thanks, it's quite right. With me now happening  mini brain storm, padding-TOP from WIDTH.  Never would have thought.. As  i understand, if we don't have any parent with a specified height, % set padding-top from browser width.

Comment: @G.F. Even if it had parent with a specified height, % set padding-top from parent width.